# Binding NSURLConnection to specific interface

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, network-programming

I am working on a small iOS application which has to download some files from a server using HTTP. In some cases, it is desirable to do this over another interface than the default (i.e., use 3G rather than Wifi).

Currently, I use the NSURLConnection (and the other NSURL-classes) to retrieve the files. However, I have not found a way to bind this connection to a specific interface/socket. I have successfully created active sockets for each interface (using the normal BSD socket-calls).

Is there any way to configure NSURLConnection to use these sockets, or another way to force it to use a specific network interface? Or is my only option to use CFNetwork (I want to do as little work as possible related to HTTP :))?

Comment: Hi Kristian Evensen, Did you get the solution? I am also looking for the same, was able to get the ip adresses of different network interfaces available (Cellular + WIFI) and verified their status (ur & running), now I have to bind a particular connection to one interface say Cellular and the other connection to WIFI. Please help me your experience on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Reachability example, it can tell you if your target host is reachable via wwan, wifi or not at all.