# Calling Web Services on interface on iOS

Tags: ios, cfnetwork

I have a unique situation where I need to call a web service on a carrier's 3/4G network to validate some data even if WiFi is enabled.  I looked at this post [Binding NSURLConnection to specific interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379094/binding-nsurlconnection-to-specific-interface) which discusses the Reachability API, but I need to send using the specific interface.

Anyone got any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Ken